# String substitution in ruby depends on variable's first character

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation, sigils

After I thought the variable scope would be the reason I got the hint, that substitution depends on if the first character of a variable is a letter/underscore or not. But I don't understand the intention. Let's take this example:

```
$var1 = "bar"
_var2 = "bar"
var3 = "bar"
Var4 = "bar"
@var5 = "bar"
puts "foo #$var1"
puts "foo #_var2"
puts "foo #var3"
puts "foo #Var4"
puts "foo #@var5"
```

which results in this:

```
foo bar
foo #_var2
foo #var3
foo #Var4
foo bar
```

I would expect for all 5 lines the same. Is it a bug? Or what's the intention of this behaviour?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. The only thing that'll get you is a suspension.

Answer (score 3):

It is not about scope. The issue here is whether `{}` after `#` can be omitted in interpolation. If you put `{}`, then any of them above will work. When you have a variable starting with a non-letter character (a character other than alphabet or underscore, i.e., `$` or `@`), you can omit the `{}`. If you omit `{}` when you cannot, then it will not be interpolated.

Comment: `When you have a variable starting with a non-letter character (alphabet or underscore), you can omit the {}` - this is not true having given examples. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse Oops, it was the opposite. I fixed.